# cat > post-receive inside the hooks folder freezes

Tags: git, cat

I'm trying to set up automatic deployment with Git with a VPS. I've created a site.git folder and I'm inside the hooks folder.

When I run the next command inside the hooks folder:

`cat > post-receive`

The server doesn't do anything, it just freezes.

Am I missing something?

Comment: So what is this command supposed to do?

Comment: The `cat` command reads from stdin and writes to stdout.  That command is expecting you to enter some content for the `post-receive` file and then manually indicate EOF.  If you are following some sort of instructions you may want to make sure you're not skipping a step.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the direction. I didn't know that but the thing is that cat > post-receive was showing a blank line where I can write the content for that file. Thanks!